# Generate a comprehensive report format in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have fetched some information form the MySQL server into R which looks like as follows in my R dataframe:

```
barcode_no   Inspection_date        current_profile      score    Tag_log   prod_log
12345678     2020-01-15 14:34:13    Large                10       C1        WIP
12345678     2020-01-15 18:33:11    Medium               20       C2        Hold
12345678     2020-01-15 13:23:24    Medium               50       C3        Hold
12345678     2020-01-15 12:12:23    Medium               70                 Shipped
12345678     2020-01-15 11:12:45    Medium               120      C1        Shipped
12345678     2020-01-15 12:22:32    Small                150      C2        Shipped
12345678     2020-01-15 15:23:23    Small                10       C3        WIP
12345678     2020-01-15 16:34:08    Small                20       C2        Hold
12345678     2020-01-15 17:07:13    Small                130      C1        Hold
12345678     2020-01-15 17:09:05    Small                40                 Hold
```

The requirement is to fit the particulars of the above-mentioned dataframe in a comprehensive report structure for date and moth wise.

comprehensive_df (Date): Will consider the latest date as per the system date if some or all the records are not available for that date then fill the comprehensive report df with 0.

```
Current_profile     # of records  % of records C1 C2 C3 [Null] # of records  % of records C1 C2 C3 [Null] # of records  % of records C1 C2 C3 [Null] Total    % Total
**Large               01            16.67        1  0  0  0      0             0            0   0  0    0      0             0            0  0  0   0     1        10.00**
Shipped             0             0.0          0  0  0  0      0             0            0   0  0    0      0             0            0  0  0   0     0        0.0
Hold                0             0.0          0  0  0  0      0             0            0   0  0    0      0             0            0  0  0   0     0        0.0
WIP                 01             1.0         1  0  0  0      0             0            0   0  0    0      0             0            0  0  0   0     1        100.00
**Small               03            50.00        0  1  1  1      0             0            0   0  0    0     02             66.67        1  1  0   0     5        50.00**
Shipped             0             0            0  0  0  0      0             0            0   0  0    0     01             50.00        0  1  0   0     1        20.00
Hold                02            66.67        0  1  0  1      0             0            0   0  0    0      1             100.00       1  0  0   0     3        60.00
WIP                 01            33.33        1  0  0  0      0             0            0   0  0    0      0             0            0  0  0   0     1        20.00
**Medium              02            33.33        0  1  1  0      1             100.00       0   0  0    1      1             33.33        1  0  0   0     4        40.00**
Shipped             0              0           0  0  0  0      1             100.00       0   0  0    1      1             100.00       0  0  0   0     2        50.00
Hold                2            100.00        0  1  1  0      0             0            0   0  0    0      0             0            0  0  0   0     2        50.00
WIP                 0            0             0  0  0  0      0             0            0   0  0    0      0             0            0  0  0   0     0        0
Total               06            0.10         1  0  0  0      1             0            0   0  0    0      3             0            0  0  0   0     1        0.10
```

I have divided the comprehensive dataframe in sections, where column 2 to 7 represent the count of those have score from 0 to <=50, column 8 to 13 represent the count of those have score from >50 to 100 and column 14 to 20 represent the count of those have score from >100.

The code that I'm trying:

```
df1<- df %>%
  mutate(Month = format(ymd(Inspection_date),'%b-%Y')) %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(`current_profile` = n())

df2<- df %>%
  mutate(Month = format(ymd(Inspection_date),'%b-%Y')) %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(`Tag_log` = n())

df3<- df %>%
  mutate(Month = format(ymd(Inspection_date),'%b-%Y')) %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(`prod_log` = n())
```

And so on for every variable. And then trying to `full_join` all the dataframe by `Date` for Date wise comprehensive format and month for month wise comprehensive format.

```
comprehensive_df <- df1 %>% full_join(df1, by = 'Month') %>% 
                      full_join(df2, by = 'Month') %>%
                      full_join(df3, by = 'Month')
```

Comment: What code do you have so far? [gt](https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/04/08/great-looking-tables-gt-0-2/) may be helpful.

Comment: @alistaire: I'm a very beginner at using R. I have tried `dplyr` and `tidyverse` library to achieve the comprehensive dataframe but so far just able to aggregate the count by `Inspection_Date` and `Current_profile` only. Not sure how to aggregate with `Current_profile` and `prod_log` together,

Comment: Group by more than one variable: `my_df %>% group_by(Current_profile, prod_log, Tag_log) %>% summarise(n_records = n())`. That won't give you the presentation format you're asking for, but the format it will give you is more useful for further analysis because it's [tidy](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

Comment: @alistaire: Yes, but need to create it in this format so that it would be much more visually clear to present the data for monthly report.

Comment: @alistaire: To be honest, this is some manual task that I want to automate as it requires a significant time to export the data using `write.csv()` and arrange it in excel in the given format.

Comment: Sure, that's possible. But if you want help, you need to make an effort and provide the code where you get stuck; you can't ask here for someone else to come up with an approach and write it all for you. But we will help you make your code work.

Comment: @alistaire: Thanks, updated the question with my approach.

Comment: @alistaire: Please suggest, does the approach seems ok to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you need but maybe something like this?

```r
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date

dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~barcode_no, ~Inspection_date, ~current_profile, ~score, ~Tag_log, ~prod_log,
    12345678L,     "15/01/2020",          "Large",    10L,     "C1",     "WIP",
    12345678L,     "15/01/2020",         "Medium",    20L,     "C2",    "Hold",
    12345678L,     "15/01/2020",         "Medium",    50L,     "C3",    "Hold",
    12345678L,     "15/01/2020",         "Medium",    70L,       NA, "Shipped",
    12345678L,     "15/01/2020",         "Medium",   120L,     "C1", "Shipped",
    12345678L,     "15/01/2020",          "Small",   150L,     "C2", "Shipped",
    12345678L,     "15/01/2020",          "Small",    10L,     "C3",     "WIP",
    12345678L,     "15/01/2020",          "Small",    20L,     "C2",    "Hold",
    12345678L,     "15/01/2020",          "Small",   130L,     "C1",    "Hold",
    12345678L,     "15/01/2020",          "Small",    40L,       NA,    "Hold"
  )



dat$Inspection_date = as.Date(dat$Inspection_date,format = "%d/%m/%Y")

today = Sys.Date()

param_date = as.Date("15/01/2020",format = "%d/%m/%Y")

dat$month = format(ymd(dat$Inspection_date),'%b-%Y')

dat$score_group = dplyr::case_when(
  dat$score <= 50 ~ "low",
  dat$score < 100 ~ "med",
  TRUE ~ "high"
)

dat %>% dplyr::filter(Inspection_date >= param_date) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(current_profile, month, score_group, Tag_log,prod_log) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(count = dplyr::n()) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = c("score_group","Tag_log"),
                     values_from = count,
                     values_fill  = list(count = 0)) -> res_dat


knitr::kable(res_dat,format = "markdown")
```

```
|current_profile |month    |prod_log | low_C1| high_C1| low_C2| low_C3| med_NA| high_C2| low_NA|
|:---------------|:--------|:--------|------:|-------:|------:|------:|------:|-------:|------:|
|Large           |Jan-2020 |WIP      |      1|       0|      0|      0|      0|       0|      0|
|Medium          |Jan-2020 |Shipped  |      0|       1|      0|      0|      1|       0|      0|
|Medium          |Jan-2020 |Hold     |      0|       0|      1|      1|      0|       0|      0|
|Small           |Jan-2020 |Hold     |      0|       1|      1|      0|      0|       0|      1|
|Small           |Jan-2020 |Shipped  |      0|       0|      0|      0|      0|       1|      0|
|Small           |Jan-2020 |WIP      |      0|       0|      0|      1|      0|       0|      0|
```

Comment: The output doesn't match with the expected output, as the expected output has those rows as well which has 0 counts.